# How to extract images from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to extract `findings` and `filename` columns from below dataframe.
[image]

For extracting images I use manual path to images having total number of 7467 images.

```
path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/iuxray/images/images_normalized"
```

Next I use the following code for extracting `findings` and images.

```
for images in os.listdir(path):
 for row in df["findings"]:
   if (images.endswith(".png") or images.endswith(".jpg")
    or images.endswith(".jpeg")):
    caption = row
    image_path = os.path.join(path, images)
    image_path_to_caption[image_path].append(caption)
```

But I want to extract images from `filename` something like this `for row in df[filename]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future posts, please paste the data in a form that can be more easily used in an example.

I think this is what you are trying to accomplish?  (Try to resist the use of for loops):

```
import pandas as pd
columns = ['uid','MeSH','Problems','image','indication','comparison','findings','impression','filename','projection']
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1,'normal','normal','Xray Chest PA and Lateral','Positive TB test',None,'The cardiac silhouette and mediastinum size ar...','Normal chest x-XXX.','1_IM-0001-4001.dcm.png','Frontal'],
    [1,'nor,al','normal','Xray Chest PA and Lateral','Positive TB test',None,'The cardiac silhouette and mediastinum size ar...','Normal chest x-XXX.','1_IM-0001-3001.dcm.png','Lateral'],
    [2,'Cardiomegaly/borderline;Pulmonary Artery/enlarged','Chest,2 views. frontal and lateral','Cardiomegaly;Pulmonary Artery','Preop bariatric surgery.',None,'Borderline cardiomegaly. Midline sternotomy XX...','No acute pulmonary findings.','2_IM-0652-1001.dcm.png','Frontal']
], columns=columns)
extensions = ('.png','.jpg','.jpeg')
path = '/conent/drive/MyDrive/iuxray/images/images_normalized'
images = df[df['filename'].str.endswith(extensions)]['filename']
paths = [f'{path}/{i}' for i in images]

paths
['/conent/drive/MyDrive/iuxray/images/images_normalized/1_IM-0001-4001.dcm.png',
 '/conent/drive/MyDrive/iuxray/images/images_normalized/1_IM-0001-3001.dcm.png',
 '/conent/drive/MyDrive/iuxray/images/images_normalized/2_IM-0652-1001.dcm.png']
```

Comment: Thanks @misterhuge for your detailed answer. I have defined my dataframe like this `df  =pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/IU-Xray/indiana_reports.csv")` do I need to replace this line like this `df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=columns)` ?

Comment: I get this error `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!` when I do like this `df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=columns)` passing whole dataframe.

Comment: That should work for reading your csv data into a dataframe.  The error is saying that the .str.endswith() is being used on a column with a non-string datatype.  Are you sure df['filename'] is the correct column in your data?

Comment: df is whole dataframe `df  =pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/IU-Xray/indiana_reports.csv")`. do I need to mention column names here?

Comment: apologies, I didn't read that error you pasted carefully enough.  My answer included extra steps to create a synthetic dataframe to demonstrate with.  replace the line in my code that is 'df = pd.DataFrame([...])' with your df = pd.read_csv('..') and you should be good to go.

Comment: it is saying the dataframe df doesn't have a column named 'filename'.

Comment: I asked another question here if you can help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74081711/typeerror-unhashable-type-list-when-using-collections-defaultdictlist