# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when using collections.defaultdict(list)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to append text column of my dataframe with image paths columns using `collections.defaultdict(list)`.

My code is like below

```
image_path_to_caption = collections.defaultdict(list)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/IU-Xray/my_data.csv") 
extensions = ('.png','.jpg','.jpeg')
path = '/conent/drive/MyDrive/iuxray/images/images_normalized'
images = df[df['filename'].str.endswith(extensions)]['filename']
findings = df['findings']
paths = [f'{path}/{i}' for i in images]
image_path_to_caption[paths].append(findings)
```

I get error here

```
image_path_to_caption[paths].append(findings)
```

Error is as follows

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: `paths` is a list, so it can't be used as a dict key. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want `image_path_to_caption` to have an entry per `image`,

```
for i in images:
    image_path_to_caption[f'{path}/{i}'].append(findings)
```

## EDIT:

If you want just a mapping of path to caption:

```
filtered_df = df[df['filename'].str.endswith(extensions)]
images_to_findings = {
    f'{path}{filename}': finding
    for (filename, finding) in
    filtered_df[['filename', 'finding']].values
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it appends 7466 records with each image. I want to append one record from `findings` column per one entry of image. It appends whole `findings` dataframe with each `images`.

Comment: Sounds like you don't want a defaultdict at all, but to just zip the files and findings columns into a single dict...

Comment: Yes but how to do it?